# The efficiency of the Update Query in CrateData

Tags: crate

When executing an update query which triggers a lot of (e.g. a million) records to be updated. As I understand, the underlying index system needs to re-ingest the doc. So for this kind of "heavy" job, is there a way to control its working load, i.e., update with a fix rate until it's finished?

Answer (score 0):

currently it is not possible to do throttling of update queries.

probably it would help for your use-case to split the updates into parts, by adding specific filters.

for example if you have a timestamp field you could just update each month seperately by adding queries accordingly.